# jointjs Reset one cell on mouse down

Tags: jointjs

I am trying to reset a cell on mouse down event. E.g if a user clicks on rectangle I would like to set its `stroke-width` to `1`

```
 paper.on('cell:pointerdown', function (cellView, evt, x, y) {
        cellView.model.attr('rect/stroke-width', 1);
        graph.resetCells(cellView);
    });
```

**But I get the error:** `TypeError: dia.Graph: cell type must be a string.`

Answer (score 0):

please remove graph.resetCells(cellView) and try again.